# Error on the login process (Invalid Request) (POST variables were not sent to this page)

Tags: javascript, php

I´m always getting "Invalid request" because of the "POST variables were not sent to this page". I already chech the javascript on the console and it was fine. And i read eveithing about this problem, maybe the problem is not the code. Can somebody please help me?

This is my index.php (login page)

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';
sec_session_start();
if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
$logged = 'in';
} else {
$logged = 'out';
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Secure Login: Log In</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/sha512.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/forms.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
        echo '<p class="error">Error Logging In!</p>';
    }
    ?> 

  <form action="process_login.php" method="POST" name="login_form">                      
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" />
        Password: <input type="password" 
                         name="password" 
                         id="password"/>
        <input type="button" 
               value="Login"
               onclick="formhash(this.form,this.form.password);"   
              /> 
    </form>

  <?php
    if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
                    echo '<p>Currently logged ' . $logged . ' as ' . 
        htmlentities($_SESSION['username']) . '.</p>';
        echo '<p>Do you want to change user? <a 
   href="includes\logout.php">Log out</a>.</p>';
    } else {
                    echo '<p>Currently logged ' . $logged . '.</p>';
                    echo "<p>If you don't have a login, please <a    
   href='register.php'>register</a></p>";
            }
  ?>      
   </body>
 </html>
```

And this is my login_process:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';
sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.


if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
    // Login success 
    header('Location: protected_page.php');
} else {
    // Login failed 
    header('Location: ../index.php?error=1');
}
} else {
// The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
 echo 'invalid Request';
}
```

And the form that seems to be working:

```
function formhash(form, password) {
// Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 
var p = document.createElement("input");

// Add the new element to our form.


document.body.appendChild(p);
p.name = "p";
p.type = "hidden";
p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

// Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
password.value = "";

// Finally submit the form.

form.submit();
}
```

And the functions:

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
// Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password 
    FROM users
   WHERE email = ?
    LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
    $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
    $stmt->store_result();

    // get variables from result.
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password);
    $stmt->fetch();

    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        // If the user exists we check if the account is locked
        // from too many login attempts 

        if (checkbrute($user_id, $mysqli) == true) {
            // Account is locked 
            // Send an email to user saying their account is locked
            return false;
        } else {
            // Check if the password in the database matches
            // the password the user submitted. We are using
            // the password_verify function to avoid timing attacks.
            if (password_verify($password, $db_password)) {
                // Password is correct!
                // Get the user-agent string of the user.
                $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                // XSS protection as we might print this value
                $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", 
                                                            "", 
                                                            $username);
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512', 
                          $db_password . $user_browser);
                // Login successful.
                return true;
            } else {
                // Password is not correct
                // We record this attempt in the database
                $now = time();
                $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts(user_id, time)
                                VALUES ('$user_id', '$now')");
                return false;
            }
           }
        } else {
        // No user exists.
        return false;
       }
     }
 }
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I removed the `java` tag

Comment: Please dump the $_POST-Var just before this line: "if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {"  -- I think the 'p' is empty, cause you submit a form with js, where 'p' has never been added.

Comment: I will try. Thank you

Comment: What should i do if the "p" is not defined?

Comment: array(2) { ["email"]=> string(34) "joaogomesgoncalves_138@hotmail.com" ["password"]=> string(0) "" } invalid Request                 This is what the var dump gaves me. Any ideia of what  i have to do now?

Comment: It´s solved. It was a problem with the database. I created a new one and it´s working now.